# Generating QR Code using PHP QrCode

Tags: php, qr-code

After using the PHP QrCode lib I discovered that for some reason when using a dynamic page with scripts and dialog boxes (JQuery) that when trying to output a QR code in a .png format I get weird symbols instead of the actual generated .png file.

Heres what I have tried:

Created a seperate file with just:

```
<?php
//include only that one, rest required files will be included from it
include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";

QRcode::png('barrda554');
?>
```

Works great,

Attempt 2:

File opened within a dialog box type using JQuery UI:

```
<?php

header stuff...
include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
...
?>
<html>
...
  <?php
   QRcode::png('barrda554');
  ?>
..
</html>
```

In this attempt I get multiple funky symbols for some reason:

```
    �PNG  IHDRWWKK/PLTE���U��~�IDAT8��ѱ � P# �c��n :V�L�@�k 
y��)�|F��5`ڸzHF|l���
%Z"e�Ы�D{\�ގ����p`�f�eh�������k�[BJeJ�c����,�^�gu�m|Q��o��W����g�
    �#�s�<�y��k�m��!v�.��(+�u���$s�-�n$߫>�gR�`IEND�B`�
```

This has stumped me and I am unsure on how I should approach this to fix it.

Let me know your ideas,

David

UPDATE:

After putting `header('Content-Type: image/png');` within the file that JQuery opens, no cigar.

Here is the actual file:

http://jsfiddle.net/T4nEP/

Comment: make sure your passing the proper `content-type`

Comment: @DevZer0 what do you mean?  I am doing the exact thing with the content it is generating.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<html>
<?php
QRcode::png('barrda554');
?>
</html>
```

To understand what this is doing, imagine that you open a regular PNG file in a text editor, and just copy/paste the contents directly into your HTML file. It's not going to show an image - it'll just be garbage, like you're seeing.

To include an image in an HTML file, you need to use the `<img>` tag, and point to the URL of the image. In this case, the URL of the image would be a PHP script that outputs nothing except the PNG contents - like this:

```
<img src="qrcode.php">
```

And then in qrcode.php, generate the image:

```
<?php
include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
QRcode::png('barrda554');
?>
```

If you need some information from the HTML page in order to generate the image, you can include it as query parameters in the URL, like this:

```
<img src="qrcode.php?product=1&format=2">
```

And then get those values in your PHP like this:

```
<?php
include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
$product = $_GET['product'];
$format = $_GET['format']
// ...
// whatever you need to do to generate the proper code
// ...
QRcode::png('barrda554');
?>
```

---

And finally - there *are* ways to include the image data directly into the HTML page, but it's not supported by all browsers, and is not recommended because it makes the page size *much* larger and prevents the browser from being able to cache the image separately.

You can see more about base64 data URLs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images/1207373#1207373) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML).

Comment: I tried this: `session_start();
include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";

QRcode::png('/live-pay/active.php?user=' . $_SESSION['userActive']);` - this is within the grab.php file that the img src calls: `echo '<img src="../member/qr-functions/grab.php" />';`

Comment: Internal error usually means a PHP syntax or fatal error. Try turning PHP error display on, or check your PHP  error logs to see the exact error message.

Comment: Nvm fixed it!  Awesome man thanks so much!  Your a blessings :)

Comment: vote my question up so I can get more points if you thought it was a good question!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following php code to generate the correct `Content-Type` header so the browser knows how to render the data its receiving.

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
```